# Vuetify- How to display data imported from external file in v-data-table

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, datatable, vuetify.js

I have one file with v-data-table component (vuetify) and another one file with my data.
I want to display data in v-data-table and Im trying to find a solution.
I dont want to combine this files, I would like to keep it in two separate files.

My code:

Mytable.vue

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    hide-default-header
    hide-default-footer
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

desserts.js

```
 const desserts= [    {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
       
       
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export the data from `desserts.js` as follows :

```
const desserts= [    { ...

}];

export default desserts;
```

and in your components import it and add it to your data option:

```
import desserts from './desserts.js'

export default{
  data(){
     return{
          dessersts,
  ....
```